# How do you freeze your cursor in Unity?

Tags: unity

In a typical MMORPG, when I hold down the right click button and drag, the cursor disappears and stays in the same position.

How does one do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this, if you hide the cursor and draw your own cursor at Input.mousePosition.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-showCursor.html

Doing so, will allow you to lock the position of your custom cursor, by simply not updating updating to the latest Input.mousePosition.

Comment: How does GW2 do it? I mean, does it make the cursor invisible and confine it to the center of the window or something?

Comment: I don't play GW2.  Can you link to a video/gif that demonstrates the behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

On a mouse down event (or, if you're feeling fancy, on the first mouse move *after* a mouse down), [hide the cursor](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Cursor-visible.html). On a mouse up event, show the cursor again.